# I can't open with MS Paint saved bitmap on sdk as jpg file 

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-widget

I save bitmap as jpg file. The source code is:

```
imageView = new ImageView(this);
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(d.getWidth() ,d.getHeight() , Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
canvas = new Canvas (bitmap);

iv.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, new FileOutputStream(new File("/mnt/sdcard/mrun.jpg")));
```

I test it on emulator. The file is saved and it has size ~150 Kb. But if I want to open it with any program as MS Paint, I receive the error message. What do I miss? Thanks.
COMMENT: I tried to write instead of the last raw the follow row:

```
iv.getDrawingCache().compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, new FileOutputStream(new File("/mnt/sdcard/arun.jpg")));
```

Same result.

Comment: The most probable reason: The file might not have been written properly, ie, not in a proper jpeg format.

Comment: Hi Kumar Bibek, I think that the file is saved ok. I succeeded to open it with GIMP as Gangnus wrote in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, that MS Paint can't work with Alpha channel. So, it can't read jpg with alpha channel. Just a thought.

try to open by some normal graphic editor. Gimp, for example. It is free.

Comment: Hi Gangnus, you are right. I downloaded GIMP now and it opens both files (saved with 2 different last rows in question code). Thanks! It's great.

Comment: This is the proof, that except buggish android/eclipse tech there exists a **much** more buggish MS tech.

Answer (score 0):

The most probable reason: The file might not have been written properly, ie, not in a proper jpeg format. Although the code seems to be fine.

This works.

```
iv.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

Bitmap bitmap = iv.getDrawingCache();
iv.buildDrawingCache();

try {
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100,
                    new FileOutputStream(new File("/mnt/sdcard/Temp/mrun.jpg")));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```